# Crash on rotation when PreferenceScreen has key

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have preference screen with key so I can show/hide it based on debug state.

Kotlin

`caller.findPreference("debug_key_screen").isVisible = Preferences.getPref(this).getBoolean(devKey, false)`

XML

`<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
        android:key="debug_key_screen"
        android:title="@string/settings_debug_title">`

But when the key is there it just crashes on rotation with following exception

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class -- expecting Preference State`

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to fix it with keys, but I managed to create workaround that works very similiarly. Instead of keys I used titles for identification. It might not be ideal, but titles are usually unique in Preferences too (which was my case).

Because I use Kotlin in my Android app I wrote extension function for PreferenceGroup which works very similiarly to findPreference, but it doesn't dive inside of the groups (because my soluton didn't require it)

```
fun PreferenceGroup.findDirectPreferenceByTitle(title: CharSequence): Preference? {
    val count = preferenceCount
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        val preference = getPreference(i)
        val prefTitle = preference.title

        if (prefTitle == title)
            return preference
    }
    return null
}
```

note that `PreferenceScreen` extends `PreferenceGroup`

using this method I could find preferences with title instead of key and evade the crash that keys caused that I never quite understood.